# What do Instagram or Facebook use on list pages?

Tags: react-native, facebook, instagram

I am just wondering how Instagram or Facebook using their feed screens as system or component?

I mean I tried everything to optimize to get at least similar performance NOT even the same just similar, but could not get a good result.

Comment: `<Flatlist />` https://reactnative.dev/docs/flatlist

Comment: no this is not correct ..

Comment: They are using their own thing.

Comment: Yeah im almost sure about that, just wondering what kind of thing is it